# Template method to get XML attribute value with type checking

Tags: c++, c++03

I'm trying to write a xml streamer which return specific types of an element attribute if the casting is can be done.
I wrote getString method to get the attribute as string, then I try to convert the string to the specific type the user requested, like this:

```
bool CXmlStreamer::getShort(const std::string & elementPath, const std::string & attribute, short & output)
{
    return getSignedValue<short>(elementPath, attribute, output);
}

bool CXmlStreamer::getUShort(const std::string & elementPath, const std::string & attribute, unsigned short & output)
{
    return getUnsignedValue<unsigned short>(elementPath, attribute, output);
}
```

For handling signed/unsigned types I created 2 method as follow:

```
template<typename T>
inline bool CXmlStreamer::getSignedValue(const std::string & elementPath, const std::string & attribute, T & output)
{
    bool isSuccess = false;
    std::string str;

    bool isStrSuccess = getString(elementPath, attribute, str);

    if (isStrSuccess)
    {
        // Converting to long 
        // if the convert is success, check valid range of the template type

        char *endPtr;
        long convertedAsLong = strtol(str.c_str(), &endPtr, 10);

        if ((str.at(0) != '\0')                                &&
            (*endPtr == '\0')                                  &&
            (convertedAsLong <= std::numeric_limits<T>::max()) &&
            (convertedAsLong >= std::numeric_limits<T>::min()))
        {
            isSuccess = true;
            output = (T)convertedAsLong;
        }
    }

    return isSuccess;
}

template<typename T>
inline bool CXmlStreamer::getUnsignedValue(const std::string & elementPath, const std::string & attribute, T & output)
{
    bool isSuccess = false;
    std::string str;

    bool isStrSuccess = getString(elementPath, attribute, str);

    if (isStrSuccess)
    {
        // Converting to unsigned long 
        // if the convert is success, check valid range of the template type

        char *endPtr;
        unsigned long convertedAsULong = strtoul(str.c_str(), &endPtr, 10);

        if ((str.at(0) != '\0') &&
            (str.at(0) != '-')  &&
            (*endPtr == '\0')    &&
            (convertedAsULong <= std::numeric_limits<T>::max()))
        {
            isSuccess = true;
            output = (T)convertedAsULong;
        }
    }

    return isSuccess;
}
```

Someone has any idea about how to write only 1 template method that can handle both signed and unsigned types (maybe float and double as well)? 
This code must support c++03.

Thanks.

Comment: You could pass `strtoul()` as a template parameter. Writing another `strtoT()` template, you could avoid repeated code and only perform this one task in a few dedicated template function specializations.

Comment: And what about checking the '-' character condition? and get the template method result as unsigned or signed?

Comment: You can still have `if (is_signed<T>::value)` (`constexpr` of C++17 should not be needed as both branch are "valid"). Not sure it is better BTW.

Comment: But having your different versions of `template <typename T> bool parse_string_as(const std::string&, T& output)` would allow to have only one `template <typename T> CXmlStreamer::getValue(const std::string& elementPath, const std::string& attribute, T& output)`.